# Control 'ctl00_txtDebug' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to render a ascx control as a view in MVC and I am getting the following error

> Control 'ctl00_txtDebug' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

The debugger stops on this line in the ascx control

```
function dtpaging_Page_Selected(vPageNumber) {
    document.getElementById("<%=mControlName %>txtPageNumber").value = vPageNumber
    <%=Post_Method %>
}
```

So I am thinking that my method is working to get the control and begin the rendering. Why would it throw this error?  I can attach more code if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question.  I have to contain the entire ascx page in the`<form runat="server">.....</form>` tags.  It really was that simple